# Instanciate a JPA EntityManager in an Eclipse RCP (Java SE) environment

Tags: jpa, eclipse-rcp, persistence, entitymanager, jpa-2.1

**Context :**

- Eclipse RCP project, divided into plugins, each one devoted to a task (eg : HMI management, communications, ...)
- 

## Necessity to persist some data in a database

```
- ORM : hibernate's JPA (JPA 2.1, Hibernate 5.2.1 used throught an org.hibernate.core plugin as constructed  [here (page 8)][1]
- database : in mysql 
- constraint : Java SE environment, so the only way to obtain an EntityManager (for the persistence operations) is to create it through an EntityManagerFactory
```

**First step (that works!) :**

Plugin that manages the database operations, its structure :

```
com.plugin.name
    JRE System Library
    Plug-in Dependencies 
    Referenced Libraries          (contains the mysql connector jar)
    src/
        com.plugin.name           (package containing the plugin activator)
        com.plugin.name.entities  (package containing all my entities)
        com.plugin.name.utils     (package containing my access functions and a main)
        META-INF/
            persistence.xml       
    META-INF/
        MANIFEST.MF
```

In **com.plugin.name.utils** I have my classes performing all the persistence functions.

In these classes, I create an EntityManagerFactory this way :

```
private static final EntityManagerFactory ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.plugin.name");
```

where "com.plugin.name" is the persistence unit name defined in my persistence.xml

In one of those classes, I have a main running some database-related functions.

**When I run this main as java application, everything works fine.**

*(to prevent future questions : my persistence.xml file was originally generated in the MANIFEST.MF META-INF folder but when running this main, it couldn't be found, so I moved it. I checked both configurations when calling the persistence functions from another plugin)*

---

**The problem :**

I need to access my persistence functions from another plugin, let's call him **com.plugin.other**

So I added **com.plugin.name** as a dependency of this plugin.
But when I try to run the application, I get the following error :

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named com.plugin.name
> at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
> at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)

When i run the main as standalone application, if there's any problem with the `persistence.xml` file (not found, incomplete, etc) it gets at least mentionned... Here I'm really stuck with no clue to understand where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it without the persistence.xml by using the createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map map) method in the PersistenceProvider.

**Code :**

```
Activator a = Activator.getDefault();
Bundle b = a.getBundle();
URL url = b.getResource("META-INF/persistence.xml");

List<PersistenceProvider> providers = PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.getPersistenceProviderResolver().getPersistenceProviders();

for (PersistenceProvider pp : providers) {

    PersistenceUnitInfoImpl pui = new PersistenceUnitInfoImpl();
    pui.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnitName");
    pui.setTransactionType(PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL);
    pui.setPersistenceUnitRootUrl(url);

    Properties prop = pui.getProperties();
    if (prop == null) {
        prop = new Properties();
    }
    prop.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://ip:port/dbName");
    prop.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "dbUser");
    prop.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "dbPass");
    prop.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    pui.setProperties(prop);

    pui.setClassLoader(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.getClassLoader());     
        emFactory = pp.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(pui, null);
    }
}
```